# try install Metron Docker 0.7.1 release fail

Tags: docker, metron

I'm a newbie for big data

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/metron
```

clone it and checkout to **apache-metron_0.7.1-release**

Then I [build **metron** in docker](https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-deployment/packaging/docker/ansible-docker/index.html) but I finally run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` not `mvn clean package -DskipTests` and I **build success**.

And then I continue to [build other container kafka,storm etc](https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-contrib/metron-docker/index.html)
after run `docker-compose up`

```
root@metron:~/metron/metron-contrib/metron-docker# cd $METRON_DOCKER_HOME/compose/
root@metron:~/metron/metron-contrib/metron-docker/compose# eval "$(docker-machine env metron-machine)"
root@metron:~/metron/metron-contrib/metron-docker/compose# docker-compose up
Building storm
Step 1/32 : FROM fhuz/docker-storm:latest
 ---> efbf73871666
Step 2/32 : ARG METRON_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d4cb4c8f358
Step 3/32 : ENV METRON_VERSION $METRON_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f4d02af86a06
Step 4/32 : ENV METRON_HOME /usr/metron/$METRON_VERSION/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9325dc9ed93d
Step 5/32 : ADD ./bin $METRON_HOME/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e3c99729a018
Step 6/32 : ADD ./parser /parser
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 499f01cd45fb
Step 7/32 : ADD ./enrichment /enrichment
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c84d2036ce5f
Step 8/32 : ADD ./indexing /indexing
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b39470f4a705
Step 9/32 : ADD ./elasticsearch /elasticsearch
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36c95dcb5151
Step 10/32 : RUN mkdir -p $METRON_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5daeb4342c7f
Step 11/32 : RUN tar -xzf /parser/metron-parsing-storm-$METRON_VERSION-archive.tar.gz -C /usr/metron/$METRON_VERSION/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d4d5e9e62fe6
Step 12/32 : RUN tar -xzf /enrichment/metron-enrichment-$METRON_VERSION-archive.tar.gz -C /usr/metron/$METRON_VERSION/
 ---> Running in 053e47c2150e
tar (child): /enrichment/metron-enrichment-0.7.1-archive.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ERROR: Service 'storm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c tar -xzf /enrichment/metron-enrichment-$METRON_VERSION-archive.tar.gz -C /usr/metron/$METRON_VERSION/' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

## Sth supplement to my question

I can't find any file in `/metron/metron-contrib/metron-docker/compose/storm/enrichment` I think this is a right path to find
[image]

And then I try to find the tar.gz to **replace it** in **.m2/repository/org/apache/metron/metron-enrichment/0.7.1/** also nothing to find , I also find in [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.metron/metron-enrichment) but only find v0.6.x.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ADD ./enrichment /enrichment` will untar all the files for you, therefore you got:

```
/enrichment/metron-enrichment-0.7.1-archive.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

try to add `ls -l` inside `/enrichment` to see what do you have inside.

here are the notice from the docs:

> ```
> Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.
>
> If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.
> ```
>
> Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed. When a directory is
>   copied or unpacked, it has the same behavior as tar -x, the result is
>   the union of:
>           Whatever existed at the destination path and
>           The contents of the source tree, with conflicts resolved in favor of “2.” on a file-by-file basis.
>
> ```
>     Note: Whether a file is identified as a recognized compression format or not is done solely based on the contents of the file, not
> ```
>
> the name of the file. For example, if an empty file happens to end
>   with .tar.gz this will not be recognized as a compressed file and will
>   not generate any kind of decompression error message, rather the file
>   will simply be copied to the destination.
>
> ```
> If <src> is any other kind of file, it is copied individually along with its metadata. In this case, if <dest> ends with a trailing
> ```
>
> slash /, it will be considered a directory and the contents of 
>   will be written at /base().
>
> ```
> If multiple <src> resources are specified, either directly or due to the use of a wildcard, then <dest> must be a directory, and it must
> ```
>
> end with a slash /.
>
> ```
> If <dest> does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of <src> will be written at
> ```
>
> .
>
> ```
> If <dest> doesn’t exist, it is created along with all missing directories in its path.
> ```